# How can I find DATEDIFF for records in the same field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a reporting table that looks like this - BEFORE:

[image]

The FREQ_CALC is the number of months between EFFECTIVEDATE and EXPIRY_DATE, divided by the noMonths field, FREQ_CODE, after the M.

[image]

I need to get everything into this shape - AFTER.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the 'FREQUENCY' as well as the fields in blue, green, and pink (pink is very easy).  Basically, 'FREQ_CODE' has an 'M' character and after that I have months and days in a month.  If noMonths is 3, I need to start mxDays with 90, and then find the difference in the number of days from the maturityDate field, so it's not the DATEDIFF() between two fields, but the DATEDIFF between increasing dates in the same field, grouped by Credit_Line_NO.  So, the three cells in yellow start mxDays.  Also, mxFactor is 1 when mxDays is 30  or 90, and it is 365/360, when mxDays is 365.  Finally, the Calc is the mxDays * Amount.  This is super-easy.  I just can't figure out how to get the mxDays and mxFactor setup.

For additional clarity, 91 days = 6/30/2018 - 3/31/2018 and 92 days = 9/30/2018 - 6/30/2018.  Also, 1.0111 = 91/90 and 1.0222 = 92/90.  Similarly, 0.8111 = 73/90.  Finally, 1.0139 = 365/360 because noMonths = 12.

Maybe this requires a CTE and a couple Case...When...Then statements.  Not sure...

I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
-- Here is my DDL
-- Drop table Reporting_Table

CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
    Credit_Line_NO    Varchar(10),
    noMonths         INT,
    EFFECTIVEDATE    Date,
    EXPIRY_DATE      Date,
    Amount           Money,
    mxDays           INT,
    mxFactor         decimal(5,4),
    Calc             Money)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('9938810','3','3/31/2018','6/12/2020','11718.75','90','1','11718.75') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('2235461','1','6/30/2018','6/6/2019','12345','30','1','12345') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('3365434','12','6/30/2018','6/30/2019','298523.36085','365','1.01388888888889','302669.518639583')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL 2008 you need to order your table with `row_number` and join each row with previous one. Then make calculations

```
with cte as (
    select 
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by maturityDate)
    from 
        Reporting_Table
)

select
    a.*, mxDay = isnull(q.dayDiff, q.mDay),  z.mxFactor
    , Calc = z.mxFactor * a.Amount  
from
    cte a
    left join cte b on a.Credit_Line_NO = b.Credit_Line_NO and a.rn - 1 = b.rn
    cross apply (select 
                    mDay = case
                        when a.noMonths = 1 then 30
                        when a.noMonths = 3 then 90
                        when a.noMonths = 12 then 365
                    end, dayDiff = datediff(dd, b.maturityDate, a.maturityDate)) q
    cross apply (select mxFactor = cast(1.0 * isnull(q.dayDiff, q.mDay) / q.mDay as decimal(10,4))) z
```

Edit:
This is update query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by maturityDate)
    from 
        Reporting_Table
)
, cte2 as (
select
    a.Credit_Line_NO, a.noMonths, a.maturityDate, a.Amount, mxDay = isnull(q.dayDiff, q.mDay),  z.mxFactor
    , Calc = z.mxFactor * a.Amount  
from
    cte a
    left join cte b on a.Credit_Line_NO = b.Credit_Line_NO and a.rn - 1 = b.rn
    cross apply (select 
                    mDay = case
                        when a.noMonths = 1 then 30
                        when a.noMonths = 3 then 90
                        when a.noMonths = 12 then 365
                    end, dayDiff = datediff(dd, b.maturityDate, a.maturityDate)) q
    cross apply (select mxFactor = cast(1.0 * isnull(q.dayDiff, q.mDay) / q.mDay as decimal(10,4))) z
)

update r
set r.mxDay = c.mxDay, r.mxFactor = c.mxFactor, r.Calc = c.Calc
from
    Reporting_Table r
    join cte2 c on r.Credit_Line_NO = c.Credit_Line_NO and r.noMonths = c.noMonths and r.maturityDate = c.maturityDate
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes!  This should do it!  Thanks so much!  You know, it is humbling to feel like you know some technology pretty well, and then realize you don't know how to do something that seems pretty easy, and then see someone else's approach to the problem.  Also, it's pretty amazing to see how powerful SQL really is.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! We all were there :)

Comment: Hello there.  I am trying to get the results of the CTE to update the original base table where the data sits.  How can I do that?  I thought it would be:

UPDATE  Reporting_Table
SET   mxDay = z.mxDay
   mxFactor = z.mxFactor,
   Calc = z.Calc

None of this works.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Uzi, I made a mistake with something when I posted my question late Friday evening.  I guess I was too burned out from work all week long.  I actually DON'T have a FREQUENCY field given to me; I need to calculate this, and then update the before table to look like the after table, in the screen shots.  I'm sure this is possible in base SQL, and I though the Cross Apply would do it, but I can't seem to get it working quite right.  Do you have any idea on how to fix this mess?  I have to use this CTE to make an Update; I can't just run a Select query.

Comment: SQL has same functions like excel and you can calculate FREQUENCY by this: `ceiling(1.0 * datediff(mm, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE) / noMonths)`

Comment: Yes, but how do I expand each record until the number of rows, grouped by Credit_Line_NO, equals the number in the FREQUENCY field?  Also, I can't figure out how to calculate the number of periods between EFFECTIVEDATE and EXPIRY_DATE.

Comment: I really can't get what are you trying to do. Earlier you said that you need to update your table. But now trying to expand rows. Then how are you going to make updates? Seems that you are mixing several tasks.